# Why is the inverted if-statement false?

Tags: java, if-statement, inversion, or-condition

Why does the if-statement count as false?

```
int money = -342;
int reviews 3;

if (!(money > 0 || reviews < 5 || reviews > 0)){}
```

Money is false,
the both reviews are true
and inverting them results with a true for the money,
and two falses for both of the reviews.
As I am using || for ´or´, one true should be enough to make the whole of-statement become true.

Comment: But money is not > 0, so that desn't make it true...

Comment: I agree with @DM, -356 appears to be less than 0.

Comment: You are negating the or conditions with your `!`. So, while the or condition itself is `true`, it's negation is not.

Comment: Why would you say "_if not money is greater than 0_" rather than just "_if money less than 0_"

Comment: `!(false || true) == !true == false`. Also relevant: [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (which tells you that `!(X || Y || Z) == !X && !Y && !Z`)

Comment: If `Reviews < 5` is `false`, then `Reviews > 0` must be `true`, and vice versa. Therefore `Reviews < 5 || Reviews > 0` will always evaluate to `true` since at least one of the inequalities must be `true`.

Comment: Ted Hopp, what if reviews is `-1`, then it is less than zero and less than 5.

Comment: And **please follow the Java Naming Conventions**: variable names other than marked `static final` *always* start with lowercase.

Comment: @ifly6 - Then `Reviews < 5` will be `true`. Regardless of the value of `Reviews`, at least one of the tests of `Reviews` will be `true`.

Comment: @MC Emperor as I´ve never heard of ´static final´ should I always start my variables with lowercase?

Comment: @ThisIsCodeMaster Yes, **always**. More precisely, variable names and method names must be in camelCase, class names PascalCase, package names all lowercase and constants UPPER_SNAKE_CASE.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/304954

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the following:

```
if (!(Money > 0 || Reviews < 5 || Reviews > 0))
```

evaluates to

```
if (!(True))
```

thus, inverted,

```
if (False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` test always evaluates to `false` because regardless of the value of `Reviews`, either `Reviews < 5` or `Reviews > 0` will be true and you are then negating the result. (The value of `Money` is irrelevant, since `||` evaluates to `true` if either operand is `true`.) I think what you want is for these three to be true:

1. `Money` must be greater than 0
2. `Reviews` must be between 0 and 5 (inclusive)

This `if` test will do the job:

```
if (Money <= 0 || Reviews > 5 || Reviews < 0) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
} else {
    System.out.println("We're good");
}
```

Alternatively, you can test for the positive conditions:

```
if (Money > 0 && Reviews >= 0 && Reviews <= 5) {
    System.out.println("We're good");
} else {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The negation symbol is negating the entire statement. Thus, if any of those conditionals are true then false is returned. If all conditionals are false then true is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses take precedence.

Take a look at the condition:

```
(!(money > 0 || reviews < 5 || reviews > 0))
```

First, the part inside the inner parenthesis are evaluated:

```
money > 0 || reviews < 5 || reviews > 0
```

Then, the order is from left to right:

- `money > 0` is false, continue to next;
- `reviews < 5` is true, so the expression in the inner parentheses is true.

The expression within the inner parentheses evaluates to `true`, so effectively your condition is equal to `!(true)` and that makes `(false)`.

*I suggest you study the basics of expression evaluation and operator precedence. Also, [as pointed out by Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936881/why-does-adding-the-in-an-if-statement-changes-it-to-false-if-one-conditional/48936948#comment84880896_48936881), you need to rethink your logic. For example, I would rewrite expressions like `!(money > 0)` to `money <= 0`, to simplify it. In my opinion, it's best to not use the negation operator (`!`) in conjunction with relational operators (like `<` or `==`), unless you absolutely have to.*

---

[Note](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html):

> The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR operations on two boolean expressions. These operators exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is evaluated only if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!(Money > 0)){...}` - *It says Something went wrong as the Money integer is below 0.* - No, it says it's below **or equal to 0.**

`(Money > 0 || Reviews < 5 || Reviews > 0)` - this is `true` if **at least** one of parts between `||` is `true`, but:

`!(Money > 0 || Reviews < 5 || Reviews > 0)` - this is `false` if **at least** one of parts between `||` is `true`. You get an opposite result with `!` (negation).

Answer (score 0):

**Why your value is false**

Money is less than zero. That is `false`.

Reviews is less than 5. That is `true`.

It then short-circuits, but if you continued, Reviews is greater than 0. That is `true`.

Regardless, the whole statement in the brackets evaluates to true because of how an or operator works. You then invert it, so it turns into `false`.

**A solution?**

Honestly, it seems that what you want is a check that money is greater than 0, that reviews is less than 5 and that reviews is greater than 0.

This means that you should probably have something like `money > 0 && reviews <= 5 && reviews >= 0`. I assume that reviews here is something like a 0-5 star range. Obviously, if it were 1 to 5, that would be different.

Comment: But after the inversion, the money is `true` and both of the reviews are `false` so overall, it should still be true. Or is it so that 2 `false` are more than 1 `true` so overall, the majority decides what the statement really is?

Comment: `money` is -356. That is less than zero. The expression `money > 0` is false. The other expressions, that `reviews < 5` and `reviews > 0` are true. An OR statement operates on a 'of all, if any are true, evaluate to true'

Comment: To be more clear, the inversion does not apply distributively to each test.

Answer (score 0):

```
!(Money > 0) == (Money <= 0)

!(Money > 0 || Reviews < 5 || Reviews > 0) == (Money <= 0 && Reviews >= 5 && Reviews <= 0)
```

It is better not to use ! before the whole statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because it is satisfying the `Reviews < 5` and `Reviews > 0` to true.
So the if statement in `if (!(Money > 0 || Reviews < 5 || Reviews > 0))` will be false because you are using **not operator**.Thats the reason it prints *We´re good*.

Answer (score 0):

Umm. wait I've been doing this for a few years now and I'm pretty sure that the "!" also applys to the "||" thus making it an "&&" meaning it will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's understand your code conditions step by step:**

```
    int Money = -356;
    double Reviews = 4.8;

    if (!(Money > 0 || Reviews < 5 || Reviews > 0)) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    } else{
        System.out.println("We´re good");
    }
```

**Given :**

- **Money = -356**
- **Reviews = 4.8**

> Let's break and evaluate the inner if condition first:
>       **(Money > 0 || Reviews < 5 || Reviews > 0)**

```
 1. Money   > 0      -356 > 0           **False**  
 2. Reviews < 5       4.8 < 5           **True**
 3. Reviews > 0       4.8 > 0           **True**
```

Now as we can see inner conditions evaluate True but if you notice there is a  (logical not) **" ! "**  operator added outside.

```
(!(Money > 0 || Reviews < 5 || Reviews > 0))
```

> Called Logical NOT Operator. Use to reverses the logical state of its
>   operand. If a condition is true then Logical NOT operator will make
>   false.

Hence when your inner condition is True the Logical not **!** makes it False.

So,   `System.out.println("We´re good");` Is executed.